# Heroku deploy errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

there is a new problem occurred

```
heroku create


/Users/ender/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts/lib/ext/heroku/auth.rb:16:in `extract_account': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/ender/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts/lib/ext/heroku/auth.rb:35:in `fetch_from_account'
    from /Users/ender/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts/lib/ext/heroku/auth.rb:5:in `user'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.21.0/lib/heroku/plugin.rb:51:in `load!'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.21.0/lib/heroku/command.rb:17:in `load'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.21.0/lib/heroku/cli.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/heroku-2.21.0/bin/heroku:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `load'
    from /Users/ender/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/heroku:19:in `<main>'
```

I write heroku on terminal as well, and I see same errors. Why?

**SOLUTION:**

You'll need to just remove the plugin by hand before re-installing it:

```
$ rm -rf ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts 
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the heroku-accounts plugin installed.

Either uninstall it or make sure you've added your accounts per the docs: https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts

Comment: no. the problem in here "heroku" command. Any heroku commands doesnot work. I had written just heroku and i saw the sam problem as before.

Comment: Ok then problem is solved by heroku supporter. 

You'll need to just remove the plugin by hand before re-installing it: 
$ rm -rf ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts 
$ heroku plugins:install git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-accounts.git